# Using WebKit to show HTML in macOS - Blank View

Tags: html, xcode, macos

Need to show HTML pages within app using WebView in WebKit framework.

This code should do it, but only get a blank white screen, no error messages.  Thanks for any help of alternate solutions.

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet WKWebView *webView;

NSURL * myURL = [NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://www.jzmobile.com"];
[_webView loadFileURL:myURL allowingReadAccessToURL:myURL];
[_webView.navigationDelegate self];
```

Comment: Is your app sandboxed? Do you have the "Outoging connections" entitlement enabled?

Comment: `loadFileURL:allowingReadAccessToURL:`: "Navigates to the requested file URL on the filesystem". See [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview?language=objc): "Use the loadRequest: method to begin loading web content."

Comment: YES!! Thanks TheNextman, There is an Entitlement called:  com.apple.security.network.client, that must be set to YES and it works!  In iOS there is a plist called: App Transport Security Settings where you list the URL's you wish to access in the app… Another gotcha when porting from iOS to macOS.  Happy to see there is at least one macOS developer out there.  Have a similar issue trying to access the CNContactStore. Get messages: [directory-services] checking if directory services are configured
 …[directory-services] directory services are not configured.  Any clue?  Thanks! John

Answer (score 0):

There is an Entitlement called: com.apple.security.network.client, that must be set to YES and it works! In iOS there is a plist called: App Transport Security Settings where you list the URL's you wish to access in the app.   Thanks to theNextMan!